# Django Template Tags Creating Spaces

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django site which is live at [this site](http://petervkay.pythonanywhere.com/police_archive/officer/1903/).  I am getting unwanted spaces in my output caused by unwanted whitespace in the HTML.

For instance, "01-1737 , Civilian Review Authority , INAPPROPRIATE LANGUAGE, SUSTAINED," has extra spaces before most of the commas.

I have found other posts with similar problems, but no solution has worked for me. I tried the {% spaceless %} tag, but that didn't work.  The only thing that did work for me was putting all of the template tags in the for loop on a single line, but I'd really like to find a more readable solution than this.

Here is the code for the Django template:

```
{% extends 'police_archive/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2> {{officer.first_name}} {{officer.last_name}}, badge #{{officer.badge}} </h2>
    <p><strong>Department:</strong> {{officer.department}}</p>
    <h2>Complaints</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for details in details_list %}
            <li>


                {% if details.incident.case_number %}
                    <a href='/police_archive/complaint/{{details.incident.case_number}}'>
                         {{details.incident.case_number}}
                    </a>
                {% else %}
                 No Case Number Found
                {% endif %}


                {% if details.incident.office %}
                 , {{details.incident.get_office_display}}
                {% else %}
                , No office found
                {% endif %}

                {% if details.allegation %}
                 , {{details.allegation}}
                {% endif %}

                {% if details.finding %}
                 , {{details.finding}}
                {% endif %}

                {% if details.action %}
                 , {{details.action}}
                {% endif %}  

            </li>
        {% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason `{% spaceless %}` didn't give remove all the space for you is because it only works **between** HTML tags. You whitespace is showing up **within** the `<li>` tag.

I can't seem to find a good solution for Django's standard templating system, but it does look like [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/) offers what you're looking for. It uses a dash to strip trailing or leading whitespace:

```
{% for item in seq -%}
    {{ item }}
{%- endfor %}
```

In order to use Jinja instead of Django's default templating system, you'll have to change your `settings.py` file as described by [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#s-configuration):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2.',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I tried to get this up and running for a little bit and then gave up.  It's only causing problems in that single file, so I've opted for the ugly single-line solution.